# FabricJs: path area too big

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to use some SVG path with fabricjs. They render well but I've some problems:

1. The are positioned wrong. I don't why, but if I remove the size from the svg string they are positioned well but I can't drag them.
2. Path area is too big as shown in the image. Shouldn't be only around the path?

[image: Path area too big]

The demo is [here](http://jsbin.com/enolul/5/edit), You can see the shapes, but they are there (try to drag the top left part of the canvas)

And [this](http://jsbin.com/enolul/3/edit) is the demo removing the dimension from the svg string

Comment: I would suggest to use `fabric.loadSVGFromString(svg, function(objects, options) { canvas.add(fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options)) })` instead, to add objects as one entity. The problem with bounding box is because Fabric takes SVG's width/height. It's something we're planning to take care of in the near future.

Comment: Ok. Thanks :) Can you let me know when this well be fixed? If I "manually" export the paths from the svg file using fabric.Path, will I get the right bounding box?

Comment: You can get the right bounding box by making sure that path elements in your SVG are fully bound by top-level SVG width/height. And that coordinates of those paths are within boundaries. You can see †his with many shapes in [kitchensink demo](http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink/) (svg tab)

Comment: Any solution for the above issue ? i'am also facing the same. I can't use the groupSVGElements() because i need to change the properties of individual elements in the path, say to change the color of each closed paths!.

Comment: To change properties of single object in grouped svg, you can still reach them by object.path[i] and change the single properties. Selecting them with mouse is not **yet** possibile. Check the updates because now the library made leap forward with svg import.

Answer (score 2):

As with current version of fabricJs in the github, this particular problem is solved.
You can load path from SVG without grouping and obtain the correct bounding boxes.